# Javascript mock naming conventions

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, naming-conventions

Whenever I'm mocking an object in javascript for testing purposes, I tend to add the prefix "fake" to it's name in order to distinguish it from the "real" versions. But now I'm feeling in doubt about that practice and am not sure if this is good or bad for code readability. On one side it states clearly that those are not "real" objects, but on the other side it differentiates the testing code from the actual code (so the test cannot be just used as an example).

Do you think this is a good or a bad practice? Is there any kind of accepted convention (or at least a widely used one) when naming your mocks/spy's/etc?

Answer (score 0):

Personally (and the company I worked for) prefix temp_ or tmp_

It is hard to have a convention for such things, the crucial thing is that you are consistent and if you work as a part of a team you make them aware, document it, or abide by their current rulings.

Also, I would be tempted to use 'pseudo' rather than 'fake'.

Edit.
In some languages it is worth merely prefixing '_' to the variable to denote that it is private to this situation.